# ARM NEON vectorization failure

Tags: compiler-construction, arm, vectorization, neon

I would like to enable NEON vectorization on my ARM cortex-a9, but I get this output at compile:

**"not vectorized: relevant stmt not supported: D.14140_82 = D.14143_77 * D.14141_81"**

Here is my loop:

```
void my_mul(float32_t * __restrict data1, float32_t * __restrict data2, float32_t * __restrict out){    
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE*4; i+=1){
        out[i] = data1[i]*data2[i];
    }
}
```

And the options used at compile:

```
-march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -ftree-vectorize -mvectorize-with-neon-quad -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2
```

I am using **arm-linux-gnueabi (v4.6 ) compiler**.

It is important to note that the problem only appears with **float32** vectors. If I switch in **int32**, then **the vectorization is done**.  Maybe the vectorization for float32 is not yet available…

Does anyone has an idea ? Do I forget something in the cmd line or in my implementation ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Guix

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [GCC's ARM options page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html)

> > -mfpu=name
> >
> > ...
> >
> > If the selected floating-point hardware includes the NEON extension (e.g. -mfpu=`neon'), note that **floating-point operations are not generated by GCC's auto-vectorization pass unless -funsafe-math-optimizations is also specified. This is because NEON hardware does not fully implement the IEEE 754 standard for floating-point arithmetic** (in particular denormal values are treated as zero), so the use of NEON instructions may lead to a loss of precision.

If you specify `-funsafe-math-optimizations` it should work, but reread the note above if you are going to use this with high precision.

Answer (score 0):

NB: Neon floating point auto-vectorization in GCC has worked for many years now, so this problem/solution won't be needed.