# Vectorization with floating point in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, vectorization, neon

I am calculating a lot of instances of the distance from a n dimensional (10-39) point to an array. I want it to go as fast as possible, for Android 4.0+, specifically for the Galaxy S3. 
I have got the hardware FPU working, but have heard somewhere that you can speed things up with vectorization and neon. 
Questions like this [Android build system, NEON and non-NEON builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679363/android-build-system-neon-and-non-neon-builds) howver don't give me a simple answer.

What is the simplest way I can use this vectorization in the S3 with an example that shows a speed up for this kind of calculation (n dim point distance to n dim vector).

Here is the loop code:

```
// go through each point in the vector
for (bi=0; bi<sizeOfVect; bi++) { 
    r[bi] = 0.0; // initialise distance

    //calculate distance in each dimension (d is 10-39 depending)
    for (di=0; di<d; di++) { 
        rj[di] = s1[i*d+di] - b[bi*d+di]; 
            // s1 is the n dim point, b is the vector array
        r[bi] += rj[di]*rj[di];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to get vectorization from a CPU (focusing on ARM); either compiler helps you or you do it yourself.

You can utilize [vector instructions (NEON)](http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/161-coding-for-neon-part-1-load-and-stores/) in an ARM CPU by writing assembly or using [intrinsics](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html).

You can get help from compiler but then you have to write vectorizable code. For an example on how to get this see this [so post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15225470/1163019).

Answer (score 0):

To use the GPU to perform calculations for you there're two routes:

- [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html): You'll use the Android Native Development Kit to create your code in C++ with calls specific to that hardware (NEON) to speed your algorithm.
- [Renderscript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html): You'll use the Renderscript computation API to process all the data and let the framework auto-parallelise it for you between CPU and GPU

I've never worked with any of them, but if I had to go for one route for a specific application I would give a try to renderscript because it is a one code for all devices type of solution (for ICS and up)